# How can I return a datetime from route with python flask

Tags: python, datetime, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to return an object attribute from a specific route. It would be a datetime return.

Below is my class definition :

```
from datetime import datetime
from app import db

class CorrectiveAction(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo_text = db.Column(db.String(500))
    realized_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True)
```

And my routing :

```
from datetime import datetime
from app.models.correctiveaction import CorrectiveAction
from app import app, db

@app.route('/action/corrective/realize/corrective_id', method=['GET'], )
@login_required
def realize_corrective(corrective_id):
correctiveAction = CorrectiveAction.query.filter_by(id=corrective_id).first()
if not correctiveAction.realized_date:
    correctiveAction.realized_date = datetime.utcnow()
    db.session.commit()
return correctiveAction.realized_date
```

Whenever I try to access this URL, my date is set up properly, but I can't get any value in return. This is the stack trace I get :

```
[2018-05-23 17:51:53,621] ERROR in app: Exception on /action/corrective/realize/1 [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FRNNUFTA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\FRNNUFTA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\FRNNUFTA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\FRNNUFTA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "C:\Users\FRNNUFTA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 921, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "C:\Users\FRNNUFTA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py", line 923, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
```

I think this error isn't related to datetime specificaly, as I get the same type when I try to return another value from my object.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the error you are seeing is because Flask doesn't know how to turn a `datetime.datetime` object into data it can send as part of an HTTP response.

[This tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/customizing-the-flask-response-class) is a good primer on flask responses.

You probably need to decide the best string representation for your datetime object and use that as the `return` value.

From [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#about-responses) itself:

> The logic that Flask applies to converting return values into response
>   objects is as follows:
>
> 1. If a response object of the correct type is returned it’s directly
>      returned from the view.
> 2. If it’s a string, a response object is created
>      with that data and the default parameters.
> 3. If a tuple is returned the
>      items in the tuple can provide extra information. Such tuples have to
>      be in the form (response, status, headers) or (response, headers)
>      where at least one item has to be in the tuple. The status value will
>      override the status code and headers can be a list or dictionary of
>      additional header values.
> 4. If none of that works, Flask will assume the
>      return value is a valid WSGI application and convert that into a
>      response object.

Since your datetime object does not meet 1, 2 or 3, Flask tries to treat it as 4 and call it as a WSGI application. That's why the precise error you get is `object is not callable`.